# Show that if E is a nonempty subset bounded of $Z$, then inf E exists and belongs to E

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Assuming that E is nonempty and bounded subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ then by definition of the completeness axiom E has a finite infium i. since i $\in E$ and $E \subset \mathbb{Z}$. Then i therefore exists and belongs to E. I think I am missing something.

Comment: By $Z$, do you mean $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Yes feel free to correct that

Comment: What is this completeness axiom you speak of? you mean that $(\mathbb{Z},d)$ with the usual metric is a complete metric space?

Comment: If E is a nonempty subset of $R$ the real numbers, that is bounded above then E has a finite supremum. I assume this is true for infinum. Also another theorem is if e is contained z then sup E $\in$ E. if the supremeum of a set which only contains integers exists then the at supremum must be an integer